# How can i write a unit test when the actual class has a static dependency?

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

```
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';
import 'package:wefocus/core/services/env_service.dart';

@singleton
class SupabaseService {
  final EnvService _envService;
  SupabaseService(this._envService);

  Future<void> initialize() async {
    await Supabase.initialize(url: _envService.supabaseUrl, anonKey: _envService.supabaseAnonKey);
  }
}
```

Here is my actual dart class. I tried to write a unit test with [mocktail](https://pub.dev/packages/mocktail) however I could not imagine that  should I mock Supabase? If yes, how can I do it? `Supabase.initialize` is a static function btw. Could you help me please? thanks

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito/issues/214#issuecomment-523662502

I have found the solution.

```
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';
import 'package:supabase_flutter/supabase_flutter.dart';
import 'package:wefocus/core/services/env_service.dart';

@singleton
class SupabaseService {
  final SupabaseManager _supabaseManager;

  SupabaseService(this._supabaseManager);

  void initialize() {
    _supabaseManager.initialize();
  }
}

// coverage:ignore-start
class SupabaseManager {
  final EnvService _envService;

  SupabaseManager(this._envService);

  void initialize() {
    Supabase.initialize(url: _envService.supabaseUrl, anonKey: _envService.supabaseAnonKey);
  }
}
// coverage:ignore-end
```

test file:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';
import 'package:wefocus/core/services/supabase_service.dart';

class MockSupabaseManager extends Mock implements SupabaseManager {}

void main() {
  setUpAll(() {
    TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  });

  group('SupabaseService', () {
    late SupabaseService supabaseService;
    late MockSupabaseManager mockSupabaseManager;

    setUp(() {
      mockSupabaseManager = MockSupabaseManager();
      supabaseService = SupabaseService(mockSupabaseManager);
    });

    test('initialize should call SupabaseManager.initialize', () async {
      // arrange
      when(mockSupabaseManager.initialize()).thenAnswer((_) async {});

      // act
      supabaseService.initialize();

      // assert
      verify(mockSupabaseManager.initialize()).called(1);
    });
  });
}
```